# Get Google Maps to print entire map displayed

Tags: google-maps, printing

Whenever I try to print a Google Map (using their interface) it cuts off the edge of the map.

How do I print the whole map showing?

Comment: You should normally always print Google Maps in landscape mode, not in portrait mode. If you use portrait mode, your printout might only fill half a page. See [here](http://www.thehypervisor.com/2008/05/printing-google-maps/).

Answer (score 3):

To save and print images from Google Maps, you should use **[Google Map Saver](http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver)**.

Google Map Saver (GMS) offers you an easy and free way to download big Google Maps on your PC as JPEG, PNG-8, PNG-24, BMP or Targa files. GMS is light (only ~400 KBytes) and very easy to run since doesn’t have an installer. You can save maps up to 12000 x 12000 pixels and then print them the way you like.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool. One downside - there doesn't seem to be any way to load saved maps with markers, etc.

Comment: This works for me apart form the fact that the "scale bar" etc is shown on the saved map and the saved map does not have enough details for printing onto large paper sizes.

Answer (score 1):

A simple thing you could try is just to take a screenshot of the map, and then print it via some other program.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this problem before, so it's possible it's your particular environment or printer.

Admittedly these are a bit painful, but here are a couple of workarounds:

- Use a PDF print driver (eg. [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/)) and create a PDF.  You might have more success printing that PDF than from the browser.
- Use a screen capture program (or even just Print Screen in Windows) and cut out the map. Paste it into a word processor or print it from an image viewing app.

Comment: Print Screen is what I usually end up doing, though this time I just zoomed out enough so that my area of interest fell in the printed area.  This happens to me on all machines, before it's even printed, you can see it in the print window that comes up.